# Mac OS: Script that does something, then starts an Application, then waits until it terminates, and finally does something?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, automator

On Mac OS is it possible to create an Automator/Bash/Java/ApplieScript that runs an bash-command to do something (*for example chance the screen resolution)* after that runs an application *(for example a game that needs a specific screen resolution)* then waits until the application has been terminated and after that does one final thing *(for example change the screen resolution again)*?

I tried to work with all Automator, Bash, Java and ApplieScript. I even tried to combine multiple of them to one chain of things that runs other things just to run something else until it terminates and then run something else, but non of that semms to work properly.

I got the terminal commands that changes screen resolution and I also got the terminal command that runs the Game, but I can't bring it together in an logical correct chain of things to happen...

The Commands are:

```
do shell script "/Volumes/Sierra/Users/xyz/Documents/cscreen -x 1600 -y 900 -r 60"
do shell script "open steam://run/8930"
do shell script "/Volumes/Sierra/Users/xyz/Documents/cscreen -x 1280 -y 720 -r 60"
```

Comment: For that purpose – monitoring a process –  you need a *run loop* for example a lightweight Cocoa or AppleScriptObjC application which monitors the game application using `NSWorkspace` notifications.

Comment: Can you explain how it works or give an code example?

Comment: The lightweight app would be the best. But you can also do it with an applescript app. Use an idle loop to wait for your game to finish.

Comment: I mean a small application created in Xcode. The alternative – AppleScript application polling for changes even using the `idle` handler – is much more expensive regarding CPU

Comment: What happens when do you run the 3 commands from a shell script? e.g. without any `do shell script` - just the 3 terminal commands in sequence... it works? if yes, you don't need any Xcode-event-programming bullshit..

Comment: sadly it does not work because it'll do the first one and immediately run the second one and then immediately after that it would run the third one. But as changing the resolution takes a while and the script is faster executing all 3 commands then the PC changing the resolution the third command runs but don't changes anything. The point is, if I do all 3 commands just like that they will run immediately after each other, they don't even wait for the previous commands to be finished.

Comment: In order to figure out when your `steam` app is running, please run `steam`, and then while it is running, start `Terminal` and run `ps -aef | grep steam | pbcopy` then click `edit` under your question and paste with Cmd+V.

Comment: Your question can probably be answered if you answer mine above.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the -W argument for open:

> -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.  Use with the -n
>            flag to allow open to function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.

So in your example I would make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/Volumes/Sierra/Users/xyz/Documents/cscreen -x 1600 -y 900 -r 60
open -W steam://run/8930
/Volumes/Sierra/Users/xyz/Documents/cscreen -x 1280 -y 720 -r 60
```

Now open should not return control to the shell until steam exits.

Comment: That looks perfect - though I have not tested it.